# mongodb search in sub-docs, or * wildcard

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, jsonpath

For example i have collection of such doccuments:

```
{
  "b" : {
    "c" : [
      {
        "d" : "e"
      }
    ]
  },
  "f" : {
    "c" : []
  },
  "j" : {
    "c" : []
  },
  "h" : {
    "c" : [
      {
        "d" : "y"
      },
      {
        "d" : "z"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It is one document. Each document contains multiple child elements with different names(b,f,j,h in this example) and array inside it.

How to find all document which contains d=z?

I can write such a query:

```
{ "b.c.d": "z"}
```

It will find all documents, which contains d=z in "b" elements. But i want to search d=z in all root elements(b,f,j,h in this document, another document have another root elements with same structure).

Is there a way to search somehow like this:

```
{ "*.c.d": "z"} ?
```

I can use "where" clase, but it is very expensive. What is the most effective way to do it in mongo?

Comment: There is no "wildcard" expression, other than what you have probably already found you can do with [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/). The "primary" reason in a nutshell is "indexes". A query without a "solid" predicate for which fields of the document ( MongoDB is schemaless afterall ) are actually being referenced for a match cannot efficiently select an index to use. So it really is **best** to keep some sort of consistency between documents and use `$or` for each path you need to search. If that's not a fit then waybe MongoDB is not for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already have such documents in mongo, so must work with it. Maybe i can somehow use text search to do that or use something like JSONPath?

Comment: Well something that supports that type of operation "if" you really need it would be more suited to that type of search. XPath queries have long been the standard XML thing and I know some databases do support that on storage. As for JSONPath specifically, I've never used it. But the key here is "database engine supporting", otherwise you might as well just retrieve the documents from whatever source and cycle through code. It's probably worthwhile to reconsider your requirements though, and rather fit your implementation to the available tools, rather than the other way around.